# Ubuntu 18.04 on Thinkpad P50 - high battery usage

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, power-management, battery

I have new a Thinkpad P50 machine with 32GB of memory. The battery life in the same system with Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 life seems reasonable.

The problem started with the upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04. I noticed a high battery consumption with the recent upgrade. Battery life comes to 20% from 100% in just about 2 hours even the system is not running any high performing applications!

It is using Nouveau display driver. My assumption is that Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't go well with Nvidia drivers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try just using the Intel iGPU (integrated GPU) without using Nouveau or the Nvidia driver (if you want better battery life). In Ubuntu 18.04, I have found it very difficult powering down the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Good chance it is indeed the discrete card not powering down. I take it you have installed `tlp`? It is very good at reducing power consumption. Also, `powertop` will be useful to diagnose the issue.